# How can I restart the script if i get a timeout exception

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

When I use this code, I get timeout exception after a while.

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.implicitly_wait(100)


def csv_url_reader(url_obj):
    reader = csv.DictReader(url_obj, delimiter=',')
    for line in reader:
        url = line["URL"]
        driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        driver.get(url)
        try:
            title = WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "some class name with title"))
            ).text
        finally:
            driver.close()
            driver.quit()
        print("Title is " + title)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    with open("url.csv") as url_obj:
        csv_url_reader(url_obj)
```

CSV File contains about 3 thousand links and after processing two hundredths of them it outputs an error. How can I get around this error? Can I restart the script from the last processed link?

Comment: You didn't specify where it times out exactly? If it's somewhere in code that you can catch, just use `try except` block and then ignore this timeout (or just log it somewhere) and continue. I'm assuming it's `driver.get(url)` that times out. Include it in your `try except` block.

Comment: File "find.py", line 318, in <module>
    EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "class"))
  File "/home/me :) /PycharmProjects/project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: moving the driver to try didn't help.

Comment: I think the browser session is over and I'm getting an error

Comment: Error appears after 10 or 15 minutes*

Comment: If you want to pick up where you left off, after successfully loading each URL, write back to the CSV a "1" (or whatever) in the second column indicating that it's complete. When you load the file, only load those that don't have a "1" in the second column.

Comment: @JeffC Of course it will throw. And it won't be caught, cause there is no `except` block.

Comment: @zemiret You're right... my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the trace you provided in comment, this line is throwing an exception:

```py
title = WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "some class name with title"))
            ).text
```

You have it in your try block but the `try` block does not have a corresponding `except` so... basically the error is not caught. Add an `except` block and it will work.

Comment: I added except TimeoutException: pass and it's gone, thank you :)